# Are limits decidable? Should definitions be decidable?

Tags: computability-theory, computer-science, limits-and-convergence, decidability

This question is about the Turing computability of the $\epsilon-N$ definition of a limit of an infinite sequence $S$. First, a proposition:

There cannot exist a Turing Machine $M$ which, given a program $P_S$ whose output is the sequence $S$, has  output 
$$ M(P_S) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} \operatorname{true} & \text{if}\,\lim(S)\, \text{exists} \\
\operatorname{false} & \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right. $$

In other words, a Turing Machine cannot decide if $\lim(S)$ exists. A short argument as to why this is the case is below.

My questions are:

1. is there another (perhaps weaker) definition of limit which is decidable?
2. a definition is "a statement of the exact meaning". Does an undecidable concept have an exact meaning? Perhaps undecidable statements are less suited to be definitions than decidable statements.

**Argument:** A Turing Machine that decides the existence of $\lim(S)$ could be used to solve the Halting Problem in the following way.

Denote $P_S\oplus0$ as the program that runs $P_S$ and upon observing the termination symbol appends an infinite number of zeros. Similarly $P_S\oplus 01$ is the program that appends an infinite alternating sequence $01010101\ldots$.

Then $P_S$ halts iff ($M(P_S\oplus 0)$ and not $M(P_S\oplus 01)$).

Hence the existence of limits, for sequences given by algorithms, cannot be decided by a Turing Machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because MathOverflow is not a discussion forum and this post is seeking to start a discussion rather than asking a question.

Comment: Now there is a question, but I don't understand what it means. What would you consider a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Actually, when you look closely at elementary analysis, lots of things are undecidable.  For example, you might consider Richardson's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem
which says that, for a very natural class of expressions, it's impossible to tell if they are equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to grow my question. I've split this into two parts: first I'd like to know if there is a decidable version of $\lim$. For the second question I'm interested in people's opinion on what constitutes a definition.

Comment: Formally, mathematics is founded on axiomatic systems, rather than on computational models; the Church-Turing thesis does not apply to (say) structures of ZFC.  In an axiomatic system, a term is well defined so long as it provably has a unique interpretation for all admissible choices of parameters.  Computability of this interpretation would be a desirable bonus if available, but is not necessary in order to usefully take advantage of a mathematical definition.

Comment: However, one can informally interpret "existential" axioms (such as the axiom of choice or the least upper bound axiom) from a "computational" perspective as providing various "oracles" that extend a base computational model.  I discuss this (rather non-rigorously) at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/a-computational-perspective-on-set-theory/

Comment: As for a more computable notion of a limit, you may be interested in the concept of metastability, which I discuss at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/soft-analysis-hard-analysis-and-the-finite-convergence-principle/

Answer (score 3):

You're right, and moreover this is *sharp*, i.e., you cannot do *more* than compute the Halting Problem using limits of computable sets.

This is called the [Limit Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit#Limit_lemma) in computability theory.

Comment: To save future readers the trouble of comparing times, I point out that this answer was for the original version of the question, which essentially just asked whether the OP's argument was correct.